# Indent to bracket not working in Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[Visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPszD.png)

Indent to bracket functionality not working in Jupyter Notebooks on Visual Studio Code. Extensions like Python Indent don't work on Jupyter Notebooks. Anybody has a clue on how to solve it?

Comment: I think Jupyter uses a different run time, thus Python Ident cannot interfere

Comment: @Iñigo de la Maza -Could you please provide us with a detailed example that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @JillCheng just added a picture so that the problem is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the "formatting" function in VS Code is provided by [the "python" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), which formats python files (.py), but does not support formatting "Jupyter" files (.ipynb).

This feature is in the plan, you could refer to it and follow it: [Notebook: Format Notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1060).

Reference: [Formatting in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).